# why should I use getch() here?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to use ncurses and play with it, so I can make an interface for a program later. In the following code, why do I have to use getch()? If I don't put getch(), it doesn't work. How can I avoid using getch()? Thanks!

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main()
{
  int       row;
  int       col;

  initscr();
  getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
  mvprintw(row / 2, col / 2, "%s\n", "salut");
  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? If you do not read any input, your program will exit right away, cleaning the display in `endwin`. It works *exactly* as it should.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'd like to print "salut" in the middle of the screen, and leaving right after. Like I'd use printf("%s\n", "salut"), it would print "salut", print the \n, and then give my prompt back so I can write other commands. You see? Sorry I'm having troubles expressing myself in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the results of the `mvprintw` on the screen, you have to refresh the screen (done), but also *leave* the results on the screen long enough to see them.  If the terminal description uses the *alternate screen* feature (e.g., of xterm), then that `endwin` call will switch back to the normal screen, hiding the results from the ncurses output.

Calling `getch` stops the program long enough to see the results.

The `endwin` call is needed to restore the terminal modes.  While (n)curses is in "screen mode", it has set the terminal (your keyboard) to "raw" mode, to allow it to read all characters.  If you do not call `endwin` before exiting the program, you will have to reset your terminal, e.g.,

```
stty sane
```

ending with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

If you do not want the screen to clear in the program, your terminal description has to not do that (as noted in the FAQ).  Aside from that, the simple display/exit scenario described can be done using the ncurses function `filter` (there is an example in [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html), but it does not account for the alternate screen).

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)

Comment: Alright I see, thanks. But I heard not using endwin can create problems in my terminal, right?